# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window — token null is not for an application

Tags: android

In my android app I am using alarm manager in mainactivity. What I am doing is at a particular time I need to show a diologue box showing whether to login or not.

AlarmReceiver2.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver2 extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(final Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

         Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            DatabaseHandler1 db = new DatabaseHandler1(arg0 );

            int count = db.getRowCount();
            if(count == 0){
                 AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(arg0);
                adb.setTitle("TNO");
                adb.setMessage("login?" );
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

                    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setClassName("com.androidhive.pushnotifications", "com.androidhive.pushnotifications.LoginActivity");

                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        arg0.startActivity(i);

                             }});
                    adb.show();

            }
       }

}
```

The alarm is receiving at correct time but application crashes by showing the error in logcat as

```
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.androidhive.pushnotifications.AlarmReceiver2: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2431)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1332)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:563)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:269)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.AlarmReceiver2.onReceive(AlarmReceiver2.java:44)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2424)
03-31 14:29:36.899: E/AndroidRuntime(1262):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: you can't do that. you need an activity to display an alert. (as mentioned in the error). Alternatively, you can display an activity that has a dialog theme.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `getApplicationContext()`, just use `ActivityName.this`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());`

Answer (score 0):

you cannot handle ui changes from non ui thread.
call activity function (showdialog()) from onReceive method of alarm manager.

```
public void showdialog()
{
  yourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
       // Create a Alert dialog and show it
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Constructor`, where you can get Activity. Like this -

```
Activity activity;
public AlarmReceiver2 (Activity activity){
         this.activity = activity;
}
```

Now, use this `activity` as argument instead of using `arg0`, which is your `context`.

`AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(arg0);`

Because dialog can't be shown using just a `context`. You need to provide an `Activity` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Context context=youractivity.this;
Then use context instead of getApplicationContext()